# Laravel S3 integration

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems

I was reading filesystem documentation of laravel, Which is not enough for beginners.

I installed `s3` package via composer :

`league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 ~1.0`

Now i have the following code, Where i am uploading the files locally,

How can i upload files to S3 with my following code.

```
public function setPhoto($file, $saveDB = true)
    {
        $stream = Image::make($file->getRealPath())
                  ->stream('jpg', 80);
        $stream = $stream->detach();
        $photoID =  $this->id . '-medium-' . time() . '.jpg';
        $photoPath = 'photos/packages/' . $photoID;
        DataIO::deleteFile($photoPath);
        $this->photo_url = DataIO::updateStream($photoPath, $stream);
        $this->photo_path = $photoID;
        if($saveDB) {
            $this->save();
        }
    }
```

I have set the credentials for s3, secrete key etc.

Comment: um it appears you are using the `rackspace` adapter and not `s3` ?

Comment: @cmorrissey sorry that was a mistake, I have updated the question, Originally i installed s3, For the question i copied that from laravel documentation. Please answer the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an instruction to do that in the doc [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#storing-files)

Are you using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) library? You can try it like this:

```
public function setPhoto($file, $saveDB = true)
{
    $stream = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->stream('jpg', 80);
    $stream = $stream->detach();
    $photoID =  $this->id . '-medium-' . time() . '.jpg';
    $photoPath = 'photos/packages/' . $photoID;
    Storage::disk('s3')->put("$photoPath", $stream->__toString(), 'public');

    DataIO::deleteFile($photoPath);
    $this->photo_url = DataIO::updateStream($photoPath, $stream);
    $this->photo_path = $photoID;

    if($saveDB) {
       $this->save();
    }
}
```

But make sure you have set properly the `s3` config in the `config/filesystem.php`